# How can I resize one of my grid cells to fit point data (QGIS 3.22.7)?

Tags: qgis

I have a grid produced with the GRASS tool `v.mkgrid`. The cells are 15' by 140,' and there are point data within it. See the image below. I am using QGIS 3.22.7.

[image]

I need to resize one of my grid sizes because the point data sometimes stop just short of the grid boundary, and it is important that I resize the cells when this is the case. I am having trouble resizing only one of my grid cells. How can I do this?

The image below illustrates the issue. I need to resize plots slightly to the right, while keeping all of the other plots the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use the "Vertex Editor" in the Advanced Digitizing toolbar.

[image]